# JavaScript program should print hoe many years you got till retire

Tags: javascript-objects

I wrote a javaScript program that spoused to give how many years you got till retire but as expected it does not work can someone help me figure it out?

```
<html>
```

//27:

```
    function people( name1 , age1){
        this.name1 = name1;
        this.age1 = age1;
        this.yearsUntilRetaire = yearsLeft;
    }

    var gali1 = new people ("gali papini" , 14);
    var jack = new people ("jhon smith" , 17);

    function yearsLeft(){
    var retYears = 65 - this.age;
    return retYears;
    }
</script
```

```
//27:
document.write("<br /> " + gali.yearsUntilRetaire());
</script>
```

Comment: thaks but now it prints :"NaN"

Answer (score 0):

Couple of issues which are just typos:

```
gali1.yearsUntilRetaire();


var retYears = 65 - this.age1;
```

But it should work for you

http://jsfiddle.net/AXy9K/